# PHP - embaralhar array

Tags: php, while, for

Estou programando uma pagina de *feed* de noticia em *PHP*.

Peço a ajuda de vocês pra me ajudarem a embaralhar a array `$tagsArray` para as postagens não ficarem sempre na mesma ordem.

Agradeço desde já!

**Código:**

```
<?php
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","newsite");

    $seguindoID= "android,Flash,iPrimePortas,";
    $tagsArray = explode(',', $seguindoID);
    $sizeSeguindo= count($tagsArray) -1;

    for($i=0; $i<=$sizeSeguindo; $i++){
        $sql = "select * from postpagina where pagina='$tagsArray[$i]'";
        $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

        while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $userPost = $linha['pagina'];
            $post = $linha['post'];

            echo "<div><label>Postado por <b>$userPost</b> - $post</label></div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você também pode utilizar a função `RAND` do *MySQL*.

```
SELECT * FROM postpagina WHERE pagina='$tagsArray[$i]' ORDER BY RAND();
```

Dessa forma a função `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, já retornará os elementos em ordem randômicas.

[**Demonstração**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9694ed/1)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente também, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de imprimir diretamente, salve cada um em um array.

```
$itens[] = "<div><label>Postado por <b>$userPost</b> - $post</label></div>";
```

depois utilize uma das funções listadas aqui [PHP: Ordenando Arrays - Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php)

como por exemplo:

`shuffle($itens)`

e imprima o resultado utilizando `foreach` por exemplo:

```
foreach( $itens as $item){
    echo $item;
}
```

sempre será impresso em ordem aleatória

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado amigo!